# Flutter grid Responsive issue on different screens

Tags: flutter, dart

How would I manage the responsiveness on different devices since the app works great on emulator Pixel 3 XL, but on real device such as **Samsung - SM-G991B with screen resolution 1080.0 X 2256.0**

as you can see all images are overlapping text does not looks good, maybe i am doing something wrong with the code..

How i can manage responsiveness on different devices ?

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: kDefaultPadding, vertical: kDefaultPadding),
                  child: Text('Меню', style: kStyleHeaders),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Builder(builder: (_) {
                  if (_isLoading) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200.0),
                      child: Center(child: null),
                    );
                  }
                  if (_apiResponse.error) {
                    return Center(child: Text(_apiResponse.errorMessage));
                  }
                  if (_apiResponse.data.length == 0) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'No products has been found..!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'BuffetBold',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: _apiResponse.data.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.72,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var product = _apiResponse.data[index];
                      return CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: product.imageMedium,
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Column(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ProductDetail(
                                      id: product.id,
                                      title: product.title,
                                      description: product.description,
                                      structure: product.structure,
                                      imageLarge: product.imageLarge,
                                      weight: product.weight,
                                      hasDiscount: product.hasDiscount,
                                      priceBefore:
                                          double.parse(product.priceBefore),
                                      priceAfter:
                                          double.parse(product.priceAfter),
                                      isHit: product.isHit,
                                      isNew: product.isNew,
                                      isSpicy: product.isSpicy,
                                      isRecommended: product.isRecommended,
                                      isVegetarian: product.isVegetarian,
                                      attributes: product.attributes),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment(-1, 0.9),
                                child: (product.isNew == '1')
                                    ? Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/new.png',
                                        width: 60.0,
                                      )
                                    : null,
                                height: 165.0,
                                width: 165.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 0,
                                        offset: Offset(0, 2))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                      child: Text(product.title,
                                          style: kStyleTitle))
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                      product.weight != null
                                          ? product.weight
                                          : '',
                                      style: kStyleWeight),
                                  Text(
                                      product.hasDiscount != '0'
                                          ? product.priceBefore
                                          : '',
                                      style: kStyleDiscount),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
                                    height: 30.0,
                                    width: 70.0,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        // ... Todo
                                        context.read<OrderNotify>().addOrder(
                                              CartOrder(
                                                  productId: product.id,
                                                  product: product,
                                                  qty: 1,
                                                  price: hasDiscount(product)),
                                            );
                                      },
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(hasDiscount(product),
                                              style: kStylePrice),
                                          Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.rubleSign,
                                            size: 13.0,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xffB81F33)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(
                          Icons.error,
                          size: 40.0,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your first container you don't have a rendered size, try to give a size to your first container, not infinity and not maxFinite size.

Comment: what do you mean by a size to first container ?

Comment: I mean the first container in your "body: "

Comment: E.g. "Container(width: 300, height: 350, child: //some widget)"